# How to put "hearty" in the sentence negatively

Tags: word-usage

A few days ago,I found the word "hearty" has a definition of

> "with a friendly, noisy, and happy manner that is not sincere" in [Longman dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hearty)

However,the dictionary doesn't give it  an example.  Also,I hardly find the example of that meaning on Internet.

Thus,can you tell me how to use "hearty" in this definition？ If possible, please give me an example.

Comment: I don't know why the dictionary says it's not sincere. Seems a mistake to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the dictionary entry is misleading.  *Any* word can have its opposite meaning when used *sarcastically*, but the standard definition of "hearty" should always be positive.

Comment: @Andrew: A learner being misled by a correctly-used dictionary makes for a perfectly reasonable question here. Errors in seemingly-authoritative material are good fodder for later searchers.

Comment: Two things to note about the dictionary entry OP links: First, the definition in question is listed fourth, behind the unexceptional 1 happy and friendly and usually loud - a hearty laugh 2 old-fashioned strong and healthy → hale and hearty at hale 3 a hearty meal is very large. Second, it is marked as 'especially British English'.

Comment: @ralph.m Um……Have you ever heard the comments from those using Longman dictionary? I'm not sure whether Longman is a highly rated dictionary. Thus, I'm afraid the definition from Longman dictionary is wrong.：(

Comment: @Sydney That's why I came here for help.：0 From my perspective,I know "hearty" is used generally as the three definitions listed ahead in Longman,but I can't make sure it has the forth fourth definition as Longman defines. Most importantly,do people in UK use "hearty" in this way? This is really confusing to me.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your help. Btw,do people in UK use "hearty" in this way?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thanks for your defending my post. That's right. Because I'm a student from the country,whose official language isn't English, looking up dictionaries is a very important manner of learning English. Thus,can you tell me what dictionaries are more reliable？  It will be very helpful.：)

Comment: @Changyo  I'm not British so I don't know how it might be used there.  Again, any word can mean the opposite if used sarcastically, e.g.:  *Yeah, Andrew, that's a **great** comment.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It appears to be an error in the Longman dictionary.** That definition appears in neither the [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hearty) nor [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hearty) entries for "hearty". I have never heard the word used in that particular sense, and I can find no evidence of such a definition via web searches.

Comment: I got you. However, it is first time I realize even English dictionaries also have errors. It is a bit unbelievable.

Answer (score 0):

In your link that you sent, there are two examples show how to use the adjective "hearty":

> I am in hearty agreement with you, and privately I am quite prepared
>   to subscribe towards it.
>
> We received a hearty welcome.

Some synonyms of hearty in specified meaning can be:

ebullient - cheerful - merry - vivacious

Comment: Yeah… pardon me,but what I ask is how to use "hearty" when it means"with a friendly, noisy, and happy manner that is not sincere".